# Elastic Search Nest create connection

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search hosted on IIS with url as "https://somedomain.com/VD1".
I am able to access above url in Postman. I am trying to connect using below query
     
     `EsNode = new Uri("https://somedomain.com/VD1/");
     EsConfig = new ConnectionSettings(EsNode);
     EsClient = new ElasticClient(EsConfig);`

On trying to create index , I am observing that query are getting formed as
https://somedomain.com/index in place of https://somedomain.com/VD1/index leading to failure.

Is there a way that I can use https://somedomain.com/VD1 for connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue was in Nest 7.0.0-alpha1 and was resolved in Nest 7.0.0-alpha2
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3749